# Transform the lists using a list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Here's the Python list I'm working on:

```
nn,mm,pp = [1 if x =='0' else -1 for x in [['0','0'],['1','0'],['1','1']]]
```

My goal is to make `nn = [1,1]`, `mm = [-1,1]` and `pp = [-1,-1]`. I can do that using `for` loop but it looks really long. I wonder is there a way I can do that using list comprehension? Thanks!

Comment: You should use separate list comprehension because it is more readable.

Comment: @ZR- were you helped by my answer?

Comment: @blorgon Yes! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are dealing with nested lists, which means for this particular problem you need to use nested loops:

```py
>>> nested = [['0', '0'], ['1', '0'], ['1', '1']]
>>> [[1 if value == "0" else -1 for value in sublist] for sublist in nested]
[[1, 1], [-1, 1], [-1, -1]]
```